# Open same url link in iframe included in the same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iframe, jquery-tabs

I have a page in which i want to implement feature like tab browsing.
I have used the Jquery Tabbed content plugin to load iframes in each of the tab.
it works fine when i load a different url in the iframe other than the parent window url but when i try to load the same parent url in the iframe , it fails.

Suppose my link is site_url/example.php
ANd within this page i have jquery tabs , in the tab when i try to load 
site_url/example.php it fails , 
but works if i have url like site_url/sample.php

Any help and suggestion would be very appreciated.
Please give your thoughts over this issue, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't Yout thinks it's like a kind o loop???

You want to place:

1. iframe with DOMAIN1 where will be
2. iframe width DOMAIN1 where will be
3. iframe withDOMAIN1..

It's possible that browser can't handle it

Comment: HI Thanks , Yes , may be this is the reason as all other links work but not the parent one. Then can you suggest any other solution to implement the tab browsing nature as we have in browser in a single browser page using tabbed content jquery plugin. I have a search form on main page with various filters , which i should also be able to copy in the new tabs and search with various filters.

Comment: Yes. It should be easy as long as You don't try to put inside iframe element your site link. Your tabs mechanism should be on your page, and below You should have an iframe with external website. In this case You don't need to put your domain with tabs inside iframe

Comment: Thanks but didn`t get your point completely ,Suppose we have a search page with filters on a page called search.php , here i am able to search only one combination of filters  , now my need is that within that single page , i should be able to make multiple searches with different filter combinations of the same form to get different results. Like we do when we open the same page in different tabs of the browser , similar thing is needed to be implemented within a same page. Therefore i thought of iframe as it creates different instances of a page within a page but unfortuantly not for itself,